# Jquery plugin not working in Facebook static HTML tab

Tags: jquery, html, facebook, static, tabs

For a facebook fan page I have created a static html tab (https://www.facebook.com/jgsportevents/app_190322544333196), where I would like to use the chained jquery plugin just like I did on the client's website (http://tinyurl.com/c3bfz93). The Chained plugin is located in the tab's basic script.js and looks like this:

```
(function($) {

$.fn.chained = function(parent_selector, options) { 

    return this.each(function() {

        /* Save this to self because this changes when scope changes. */            
        var self   = this;
        var backup = $(self).clone();

        /* Handles maximum two parents now. */
        $(parent_selector).each(function() {

            $(this).bind("change", function() {
                $(self).html(backup.html());

                /* If multiple parents build classname like foo\bar. */
                var selected = "";
                $(parent_selector).each(function() {
                    selected += "\\" + $(":selected", this).val();
                });
                selected = selected.substr(1);

                /* Also check for first parent without subclassing. */
                /* TODO: This should be dynamic and check for each parent */
                /*       without subclassing. */
                var first = $(parent_selector).first();
                var selected_first = $(":selected", first).val();

                $("option", self).each(function() {
                    /* Remove unneeded items but save the default value. */
                    if (!$(this).hasClass(selected) && 
                        !$(this).hasClass(selected_first) && $(this).val() !== "") {
                            $(this).remove();
                    }                        
                });

                /* If we have only the default value disable select. */
                if (1 == $("option", self).size() && $(self).val() === "") {
                    $(self).attr("disabled", "disabled");
                } else {
                    $(self).removeAttr("disabled");
                }
                $(self).trigger("change");
            });

            /* Force IE to see something selected on first page load, */
            /* unless something is already selected */
            if ( !$("option:selected", this).length ) {
                $("option", this).first().attr("selected", "selected");
            }

            /* Force updating the children. */
            $(this).trigger("change");             

        });
    });
};

/* Alias for those who like to use more English like syntax. */
$.fn.chainedTo = $.fn.chained;

})(jQuery);

$("#bestemming").chained("#sport"); /* or $("#series").chainedTo("#mark"); *///         Javascript Document
```

Furthermore I am calling the tab's script page with [[script.js]] in the tab's index.html file, and jquery with http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js'> . Unfortunately I can't get the plugin to work like it does on my client's website.

What is going wrong?

**Update**

Based on Fabio Antunes' answer I have changed the code. Unfortunately its still not working. I've changed the code but still no effect.

Answer (score 2):

Your jquery is being blocked, facebook blocks every script that comes from a non secure url,
so change this:

`http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js`

To this:

```
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js
```

One more thing your font is also being blocked for the same reason:

```
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300
```

You just need to change the protocol to https

```
https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto+Condensed:300italic,400italic,700italic,400,700,300
```

**EDIT**

You have one more error on your code, you're not loading the facebook javascript properly, making your app firing a javascript error, because of this you're app won't run any script

change this:

```
<script>
  FB.init({
    appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
</script>
```

to this:

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
  FB.init({
Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined
    appId  : 'YOUR_APP_ID',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
  });
  FB.Canvas.setAutoResize();
  };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
      (function(d){
         var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
         ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
       }(document));
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Unfortunately its not working. I've changed the code but still no effect. On the index.html I am calling script.js which containts the following code from the "chained plugin":

Comment: Thanks for your help, I've changed it but its still not working.

Comment: why are you including the chained code on your html instead of loading the script as a js.file as you done on your website?

Comment: You still have errors on your page, go to your facebook page https://www.facebook.com/jgsportevents/app_190322544333196 and open the firebug or the google chrome developer tools and check the console tab, the chained.js file you included is not loaded because you're loading from your wordpress domain, and this domain does not have SSL, you must load that file from a domain that allows the HTTPS protocol. And the facebook javascript SDK is firing an error, you're using a wrong domain or url on the authentication